# Panda converting data to NaN when adding to a new DataSet

Tags: python, pandas

I´ve been trying to extract specific data from a given data set and add it in a new one in a specific set of organized column. I'm doing this by reading a CSV file and using the string function. The problem is that even though the data is extracted correctly Pandas will add the second column as NaN even though there is data stored in the affected variable, please see my code below, any idea on how to fix this?

```
processor=pd.DataFrame()
Hospital_beds="SH.MED.BEDS.ZS"
Mask1=data["IndicatorCode"].str.contains(Hospital_beds)
stage=data[Mask1]
Hospital_Data=stage["Value"]
Birth_Rate="SP.DYN.CBRT.IN"
Mask=data["IndicatorCode"].str.contains(Birth_Rate)
stage=data[Mask]
Birth_Data=stage["Value"]
processor["Countries"]=stage["CountryCode"]
processor["Birth Rate per 1000 people"]=Birth_Data
processor["Hospital beds per 100 people"]=Hospital_Data
processor.head(10)
```

Comment: I'm assuming the csv contains data from the world bank. Can you please provide the query used to download it? (Generally when providing code examples it's best to [provide code people can use to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sure , is the world development indicators data set. You can download it from kaggle. Thank you for getting back to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the indices are not matching up. When you initially populate the `processor` data frame you are using each line from the original dataframe that contained birth rate data. These lines are different from the ones that contain the hospital beds data so when you do

`processor["Hospital beds per 100 people"] = Hospital_Data`

pandas will create the new column, but since there are no matching indices for the `Hospital_Data` in `processor` it will just contain null values.

Probably what you first want to do is re-index the original data using the country code and the year

`data.set_index(['CountryCode','Year'], inplace=True)`

You can then create a view of just the indicators you are interested in

`indicators = ['SH.MED.BEDS.ZS', 'SP.DYN.CBRT.IN']
dview = data[data.IndicatorCode.isin(indicators)]`

Finally you can then [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) on the indicator code to view each indicator on the same line

`dview.pivot(columns='IndicatorCode')['Value']`

But note this will still contain a lot of NaNs. This is just because the hospital bed data is updated very infrequently (or e.g. in Aruba not at all). But you can filter these out as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much , it did work like a charm, now I´m working on filtering out all the NaN values and replacing them by zeroes. One question though, how did you decide to re index the data by Country Code and Year? Is it because these were parameters for the rest of the data?

Comment: In this case I just happen to know the world bank publishes indicators by country and year (their website will also tell you that). Usually you can get a good sense by inspecting what you see in `data.columns` or `data.head()`. When possible though it's better to have same knowledge of how the raw data is structured.